# How to execute a function only once in a day(&only if the app is opened)?

Tags: javascript, logic

Let i have a function

```
     function alert(){
                    alert("notification") 
                     }
```

this function is a part of a mobile app, i want to show this alert(execute function) only once in a day only if user opens the app,

if user didn't open the app for so many days it shouldn't execute that function for that much days.
How to implement in javascript?
can anyone provide a common logic that can be used every where even in ios or ionic...etc ?

Comment: i edited little.. check it

Comment: Store a variable in something like localstorage, containing the date the last time the function was called. Then when the app is opened, check if that function was run more than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select somewhere that you can store persistent data. That will depend on whatever APIs the app supplies.

Use `new Date()` to find out the current time.

Compare that to the stored time the function last executed fully. If it is less than a day, return immediately.

Otherwise, store the new time and let the rest of the function run.

Comment: I had a similar thought. I wonder if that persistent data would be localStorage.

Comment: Local storage would be an option if it is an API exposed to your app.